# What library to use for a java based media player?

Tags: java, audio

I'm working on developing a media player like application in Java (it's a swing based application) and I want it to be able to run on smoothly using as many different file formats as possible. I want to be able to take in a bunch of music files, then retrieve their tag information (artist/album/songname/etc), and then later play them. I've done a bit of poking around but it's hard to find a library which will support .m4a, .mp3. and maybe even .flac files. Does anyone know of a library which will do what I want? Thanks!

Comment: Does it need to be free and/or open source? What license conditions are you OK with?

Comment: Free/open source would be optimal, but I'm not unwilling to look at other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMF is, to put it in the nicest possible way, rather out of date, unmaintained, difficult to distribute and in my experience has quite a few annoying bugs that crop up where you least expect them. And if you can get FMJ to work at all, good luck - they pride on it being an up to date, drop in replacement but my experience begs to differ on both those points.

Personally I wouldn't even consider it - just use separate libraries for each format or bunch of formats you want to support. [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) would be a good one to start with as it can do a fair few, [JFlac](http://jflac.sourceforge.net/) will do your flac files on top of that.

Comment: JLayer looks pretty good, I'll start using that for now, then add additional libraries to support other formats if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's JMF - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework, which also lists some alternatives. I've had rather mixed success with JMF; it worked well for some static MPEG files but didn't seem compatible with the streaming sources we were using at the time (a couple of years ago).

Comment: Aye, i've looked at JMF and it doesn't seem to support mp3 or m4a (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html). FMJ seems to support mp3 and other stuff, but not m4a.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to jFLAC for FLAC files is to use the official libFLAC, invoked via the *Java native interface*. See [this blog post](https://klipspringer.avadeaux.net/decoding-the-flac-audio-format-in-java/), under the headline “FLAC decoding with Java native interface” for an explanation of how it's done, with links to working code.